# Self hosting map vector tiles for web application

Tags: web-services, map, hosting, geospatial

I'm building a web application, which involves (currently) a REST backend and a frontend SPA. The backend is hosting massive geo-enabled data, and the frontend is displaying it on a mapbox map. I'm hitting performance issues, because of the stack I set up. Here's the stack, when it comes to displaying a map.

```
    MapboxGl.js player
        ^          ^
        | (HTTP)    \
 Node.js backend     Mapbox APIs vectors
        ^
        |
     MongoDB
```

The HTTP endpoints serve both *GeoJSON* and REST data. The GeoJSON part is dynamically generated from a set of MongoDB collections (say, `gpspoints`, `images`, `lines` etc.). The Mapbox API is my Mapbox Studio style.

I'm looking for the best alternative to this design. And reading about maps, vectors, tiles, rendering and stuff, I came up to the idea that I should trade my GeoJSON server for a Vector tiles server (only for the map part). I'd like to end up with something like.

```
         MapboxGl.js player
       ^         ^           ^
      /          | (HTTP)     \
Vector tiles  Node.js backend   Mapbox APIs vectors
   Server            ^
     ^               |
     |               |
Other backend ?   MongoDB
```

---

I'm struggling at the point of making design choices.
The questions I have in mind are :

**About generating :**

- I came to the idea that I must *generate* my vector tiles from a GeoJSON. Is that correct ? Would it be possible to generate vector tiles from scratch, I mean, say, from a node.js routine script, parsing datas from various sources (.csv, other databases, etc.) and make operations on it (using turf.js), then generating vector stuff, like pushing, maybe updating, deleting, etc ?
- I found [geojson-vt](https://github.com/mapbox/geojson-vt) which seems to be able to translate GeoJSON to vector tiles, but only in json format. I found [vt-pbf](https://github.com/mapbox/vt-pbf), am I on the right direction ?

**About serving**

- Once I would have been able to generate whatever-format-vector-tile, I am going to be willing to serve it. I found [Tilelive.js](https://github.com/mapbox/tilelive) which seems very good, and has plenty of modules, including backend ones. Is that a good option ?
- Speaking generaly, would it be possible not to generate any static file stuff, and maybe dynamically serve any-vector-format from a database, **through** something like tilelive ?

---

Additional info :

- My datas are "mutable", but I have routine scripts that run at night and parse new datas. Thus, live-map-displayed-data mutability is not a requirement : I can update / re-parse a whole dataset at night to serve it on the morning
- Both generating and hosting on Mapbox studio is not an option, since my data is critical and must be hosted in specific coutries. A self-hosted option is mandatory, any cloud-based stuff is not ok :/

---

This question is redundated in [gis.stackexchange](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/255926/self-hosting-vector-tiles)

Comment: Isn't there any open-source forks of mongo that retrieve data as Vector tiles?

Comment: Hey Emerson, thanks. I couldn't find anything about it

Comment: Not sure if this helps you, but take a look, it seems to be a backend serving vector tiles using mongo; but it uses mapnik instead for the vector tiles: https://github.com/geopan/mongodb-express-tileserver